# using $ symbol for a password inside yml file in grails4

Tags: groovy, passwords, yaml, datasource, grails-4

my database has a password something like "abc_$123" or "abc$xyz". i want to retain $ as part of the password.

but grails 4 is interpreting characters after the $ as a variable, and if i use an escape character /, it says invalid escape character.
Escape character used to work fine with grails 3, but causing issues with grails4.

environments:
development:
dataSources:
dataSource:
pooled: true
dbCreate: none
url: "example"
username: "example"
password: "abc_$123"

Tried the password like 'abc_$123', "abc_$123", "abc_\$123", "abc_$\\123", abc_$123, etc..
None of them seem to help. Either i get invalid escape character error, or Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: 123 for class: SimpleTemplateScript1